# Benefits of .centerCrop()

Tags: android, android-glide, image-loading, scaletype

I'm asking this question out of curiosity. Basically I'm using `glide` for loading images into `imageView` by setting the `scaleType` of image to `centerCrop` .But what I'm asking is **Is it worth or good practice to use the glide's centercrop method instead of imageview's scaletype?**.

I'm asking this because as far as I know glide will first download the image and then transform it into required shape .So, I don't think it will increase the downloading speed of image. Then where this method is useful?

Comment: Have you found an answer yet?

Comment: @Locdoc01 no not yet